# User coming as null while authenticating with passport js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, express, passport.js

I am new to Node/mongodb/passport, trying to authenticate using passport. 
here is my auth.js

```
var User = require('../models/userModel'),
  passport = require('passport'),
  BasicStrategy = require('passport-http').BasicStrategy,
  jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

passport.use(new BasicStrategy(function(userid, password, done){
  User.findOne({ 'userid': userid }, function(err, user){
    if(err){ 
      return done(err); 
    }

    if(!user){ 
      return done(null, false); 
    }

    if(!user.verifyPassword(password)){ 
      return done(null, false);
    }

   return done(null, user);
  })
}));

exports.generateToken = function(req, res, next){
  req.token = jwt.sign({ id:req.user.userid },'secret key', { expiresInMinutes:120 });
  next();
};

exports.respond = function(req, res){
  req.status(200).json({
    user: req.user,
    token:req.token
  });
};

exports.isAuthenticated = passport.authenticate('basic', {session:false});
```

For database, I simply created a user to test in the following way:

`db.UserSchema.insert({"userid": "hm", "password":"mm123"})`

here is my userModel.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userid: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  access_token: String
});


UserSchema.methods.verifyPassword = function(password, cb) {
  bcrypt.compare(password, this.password, function(err, isMatch) {
    if (err) return cb(err);
    cb(null, isMatch);
  });
};
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

when I send a request using postman and debug using node-inspector, user come as  null in auth.js and in console

```
Runtime.getProperties failed.
Error: No scopes
```

here is the server.js

```
var express = require('express'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    path = require('path'),
    passport =require('passport'),
    authentication = require('./auth/auth');


var db;
if (process.env.ENV == 'Test') {
  db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/fxtest');
}else{
  db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/fx');
}

var app = express();

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(port, function(){
  console.log('Running on Port using gulp:', port);
});
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.post('/auth',authentication.isAuthenticated,
 authentication.generateToken, authentication.respond);
module.exports = app;
```

Can anyone give me any leads as to what am I missing here??

Comment: can you show your server code where your express app is using the auth.js file?

Comment: @peteb, added the server code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it resolved. The problem was I had given the collection name as `UserSchema`, whereas my model name was `User`. As stated in mongoose docs [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html):

> Mongoose automatically looks for the plural version of your model
>   name

and so it was looking for `users` as a collection.

Answer (score 0):

You're responding with the request object which you can't do. You need to respond on the response object.

Its also worth pointing out, that unless you have a cleanup procedure that needs to happen after you respond, you should use a `return` with your `res` object.

```
exports.respond = function(req, res){

  // This is wrong
  req.status(200).json({ 
    user: req.user,
    token:req.token
  });

  // This is correct
  return res.status(200).json({
    user: req.user,
    token: req.token,
  });
};
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out a mistake, but the control never reaches to that point. in the user.fineOne method only user comes as null.

Comment: Add `app.use(bodyParser.json());` before your routes.